# WPF ContextMenu on Left Click only show but don't let me click

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm developing a menu bar using only `Controls:Tiles` with the attribute `ContextMenu` which only let me open it clicking on right mouse button. After some search I made it clickable with left mouse button but the behaviour is different: When I press right click `ContextMenu` opens and all `MenuItems` are clickable. When I press left click `ContextMenu` opens but all `MenuItems` looks disabled and I can't click on them.

My code is here:

```
<Controls:Tile x:Name="FileTile" Width="Auto" Height="30" TitleFontSize="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Background="White" HorizontalTitleAlignment="Right"
                                       Foreground="Gray" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="True">
                    <Controls:Tile.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto">
                            <Image Source="/images/topbaricons/files.png" Width="22" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.File}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Controls:Tile.Content>
                    <Controls:Tile.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Controls:Tile.Style>
                    <Controls:Tile.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu x:Name="File_ContextMenu" >
                            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Menu_item_New}" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" IsEnabled="true">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/images/topbaricons/new_file.png" Height="22" Width="22" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Menu_item_Open}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" IsEnabled="true">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/images/topbaricons/open_file.png" Height="22" Width="22" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Menu_item_Save}" x:Name="MenuItemSave" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" IsEnabled="False">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/images/topbaricons/save.png" Height="22" Width="22" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.SaveAs" Visibility="Visible" >
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/images/topbaricons/save_as.png" Height="22" Width="22" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Menu_item_Exit}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" IsEnabled="true">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/images/topbaricons/off.png" Height="22" Width="22" />
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Controls:Tile.ContextMenu>
                </Controls:Tile>
```

To show exactly the difference I've been talking about on this post there's this image:

[image: Left-Right Click Behavior]

Can someone help me? I really wanna do with left click the same I can do with right click.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Elhamer

Comment: Do you click on the same place?

Comment: @Rekshino yes i do! The only change is the click being on left or right button

Comment: Where do you bind your commands?

Comment: I bind my commands like this:

`<Window.CommandBindings>

        <CommandBinding Command="New" Executed="NewCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
        <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="OpenCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>

        <CommandBinding Command="Save" Executed="SaveCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
        <CommandBinding Command="SaveAs" Executed="SaveAsCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
        <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="CloseCommand_Executed"></CommandBinding>
    </Window.CommandBindings>`

Comment: Try to put `CanExecute` to the bindings or put them to the ´ContextMenu´ tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the `CanExecute` for the commands will be handled somewhere(maybe element currently focused has own implementation). Pasting

```
<ContextMenu.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SaveAs" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
</ContextMenu.CommandBindings>
```

and

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
    //e.Handled = true;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: The only thing I needed was binding my commands inside the ContextMenu just like you did. I only did a few changes at it worked fine! I really appreciate your help! Thanks!